# "たものですか" "used to" is not convincing in my example

Tags: grammar

こんにちは
I searched about the meaning of "たものですか" and I found out it means " used to " but in my example "used to " is not logic

here's my example 
(snippet from a conversation in a book)

A:この絵はすごいですね.いつごろかかれたものですか

Ｂ：ええっと.14せいきにかかれたそうです.

here in A's sentence " when it's used to be drawn " is not logic for me !
can any one help me translate the sentence of A and tell me the meaning of ""たものですか" here what ?

Comment: Put your sentence in Google translate and it parses SOME (but not all) word boundaries for you in the romaji transcription: "Kono e wa sugoidesu ne. Itsu-goro kakareta monodesu ka."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> いつごろ　かかれた もの　ですか
>   
>  When was it drawn?

The sentence could probably be interpreted more awkwardly as

> What period of time is this drawn thing [the drawing/painting]?

which might explain how you get the above translation.

もの refers to "thing", so

> いつごろ　の　もの　ですか
>   
>  When was this?

could be interpreted more literally as

> This thing is of what time?

which because your questions are around some work of art (painting, statue):

> What time period did this work originate from?